# How do I segment my code into re-usable composer packages in PHP?

Tags: php, composer-php

I wrote my framework. It has a few hardcoded things that make it what it is and then it has all these modules that it simply ingests. Now, I was thinking that it'd be exceptional if I could re-use some of these modules outside of my framework.

Even if they're plug & play, you have to copy the folder to your new project and then make sure that module's dependecies are met, because in your module, you might be relying on some other modules.

But there's a huge, huge problem. What if, within the same space, say a website, two different sides of it require my `RequiredPackage`. How do I ensure that if the `RequiredPackage` is already installed, I don't run into issues where I have to `if( class_exists() )` on every single file?

So, in short, I'd like to be able to, in any folder's composer.json specify that this part of the website requires `ReduiredPackage` but it shouldn't run into "class already declared" issues.

Comment: Have you tried looking into how other frameworks solve this? For example, Symfony provides a composer.json with each component. When there was still the symfony/symfony metapackage, tying it together, it just utilized the `replace` section in the composer.json. Sounds like this could work for you. Maybe you want to add more info like your directory structure and composer.json for a better context to work on

Comment: @dbrumann Doing it right now with Laravel! I just don't understand exactly how this will help me when I run `composer install` so that, if multiple packages rely on one package, in my case, one would be `sprout\sprout_privileges` that it doesn't install it inside each of these packages. Is there no way to install a package globally within a project?

Comment: I don't understand your issue, to be honest. If multiple dependencies require the same library, e.g. `sprout/sprout_privileges` then composer should install only one version of that library, that matches the requirements from both dependencies. Could you maybe give a more detailed explanation of the problem and how to reproduce it?

Comment: @dbrumann I re-asked my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56518219/how-do-i-make-my-required-package-global-without-conflicts-in-composer-php . This is my issue.