# How do I make my required package global, without conflicts in composer-php?

Tags: php, composer-php

Assume I have a package `sprout_services` that 3 other packages I'm using `require`. Once the first package to run has required it, then it is open in the global space.

From anywhere in my application, I can do `new SproutServices\ServiceLocator`. Now, once I've had my second package initialize this `sprout_services`, I will inevitably be hit with the issue of `Class has already been declared` since I'm trying to re-define the same classes that were autoloaded before.

How can I make this `sprout_services` package open in the global state **without overriding it** and entering conflicts of "hey, I was the first here!"?

Comment: Are you using `require` inside the class using the ServiceLocator?  Could you maybe show the code? Could it be that you need [`require_once`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) or, since composer takes care of autoloading, not use a require statement at all?

Answer (score 0):

I panicked for nothing.

Once a dependency is resolved and therefore included by composer, it'll enter the global namespace and cannot be overwritten. Composer knows and sees this and it'll not attempt to re-load.

I am not sure what happens if my class names are identical for different versions, I will update this answer as I find more.